# What is the best way to install nodejs on OSX?

Tags: node.js

I see you can `download nodejs` via `homepage` or `install via homebrew` or `via macports`.

which is the best method?

Is there a reason for choosing one over the other?

```
Some things I consider:
1. Ease of upgrading to latest version
2. Ability to (fully) remove and uninstall
3. 1 and 2 should leave no trace of old version (including any temp files), or in case of uninstalling, should fully remove everything.
```

Comment: I've been using macports for over 2 years now, very happy with Node, MongoDB, Redis, etc. Used to have homebrew but for some reasons I didn't click with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [Mac OS X Installer](http://nodejs.org/download/) as upgrading is easier in the future.

Comment: If a new version comes out and I run that installer, will it automatically update all the files or would I have to uninstall the old version before upgrading? If uninstall is required, how to "fully" uninstall?

Comment: It handles the upgrade for you.

Comment: DON'T. I'm sure many will come to this question before installing node/npm. On a development/normal machine, it should definitely be installed with brew, otherwise everything requires sudo, things are pretty messed. Probably everything should be installed with brew if possible

Answer (score 33):

I prefer to use `brew`.

once installed its as easy as:

`brew install node`

Done and done.

Don't want it anymore?

`brew uninstall node`

Need to upgrade?

`brew upgrade node`

Plus, its based on `git` and the community is very active.
Furthermore, the packages that are installed are always in one place, then symlinked to your `/usr/local/bin`, so no messy `sudo` or multiple install locations.

[Checkout the site here](http://brew.sh)

Comment: I've been a Windows guy for many years. For about a year I've been using Ubuntu and been extremely happy with it. I was pretty convinced that was going to be my main OS going forward. Then I got a new job and they handed me a MacBook Pro. At first I wasn't convinced about OSX, but then I discovered homebrew. Brew is what sold me. The power of a full UNIX terminal combined with a great package manager like brew then layered over with OSX's polished GUI has pretty much turned me into an OSX fan. +1 for brew.

Answer (score 4):

I personally like to compile from source.
https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installation

You can use NVM for upgrades and downgrades and even switching between different versions at any moment!
https://github.com/creationix/nvm

Comment: Why do want to always compile from source ?

Comment: Maybe I was a little eager there. Truthfully, @sparrow is right - brew is probably the fastest and easiest method on OSX. I think it's really a matter of preference. In any case, NVM is a great tool for managing versions.